# Calculate Column Based on Dates Matching

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have data in two different sheets (Raw Data and Reference Data). The Raw Data has multiple profit lines of the same date. I would like to pull this data as a total sum based on date to the Reference Data sheet. i.e the total profit for May 1st, 2nd etc. What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Reference Sheet:
[image: Reference Sheet]

Raw Data:
[image: Raw Data]

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What have you tried so far? Do you know how to use `SUMIF` function?

Comment: I've been trying the SUMIF function but I can't seem to get the order of the formula correct. Closest I've come is a "0" and a total of all profit lines, not just those dates.

Comment: I've gotten close enough where it can compare the two dates and if true returns a result, but I can't get that result to be only the profit that correlates with those specific dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapt the following formula to your workbook:

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$8,$E1,$B$1:$B$8)
```

Drag down to fill the other cells.

[image]

You select to range to match (where the date must be found), then the criteria (the date to find) followed by the range to sum.

See [SUMIF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b).